# Django query using OR

Tags: django, django-models

I have a queryset of `providers`:

```
>>> provider_qs = Provider.objects.filter(...)
[<Provider: Gin Investors>, <Provider: IND INVESTORS>]
```

What would be the query to get all financial statements for those providers? Something like -

```
>> fs = FinancialStatement.objects.filter(provider__in provider_qs)
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply do:

```
fs = FinancialStatement.objects.filter(provider__in=provider_qs)
```

Django optimizes this into one SQL query. There is an example exactly for this in the [Django QuerySet documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
inner_qs = Blog.objects.filter(name__contains='Cheddar')
entries = Entry.objects.filter(blog__in=inner_qs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line:

```
fs = FinancialStatement.objects.filter(provider__whatever__more='asd')
```

or using example from **Mitar**'s answer:

```
entries = Entry.objects.filter(blog__name__contains='Cheddar')
```

You should really read more on [Django querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/).